# Interchange derivative and argmin

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

Let $y(x) = \arg \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}^+} \{g(x,y)\}$ for some function $g$ and any given $x$. Then, if I want to determine whether $y(x)$ is non-increasing/decreasing in $x$, how can I interchange $\partial y(x) / \partial x$ with the $\arg\min$ function (i.e., which condition(s) are required)?

Any idea will be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I warmly recommend going through our tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Note that Corollary 2 of [From perspective maps to epigraphical projections](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/full/10.1287/moor.2022.1317?casa_token=rUgw4TIHO4wAAAAA%3AIQGftoeh3i4ZE-X9KXZhKWRRwaHemYS-oy9oK3_4rOlM3YPGcHklLUHp8GtiYqEyfci5kmWglfs) (Friedlander, Goodwin & Hoheisel, 2022) provides an alternative viewpoint to the answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Let me denote $h(x) = \arg \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}^+} \{g(x,y)\}$ for clarity.
This helps make a difference between the variable $y$ in $g(x,y)$ and the function.

First of all, it is not true that $h'(x) = \arg \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}^+} \{\partial_xg(x,y)\}$, so you cannot simply exchange the derivative with the $\arg\min$.
For a simple example of this, consider $g(x,y)=y^2$.

There is a way to calculate $h'(x)$, though, if $g$ is nice.
It is enough to assume that the minimum exists uniquely for all $x$, that $g\in C^2$, and that $\partial_y^2g(x,y)>0$ at $y=h(x)$.
To find the derivative, start with observing that the partial derivative has to vanish: $\partial_2g(x,h(x))=0$.
Here I denote by $\partial_2$ the derivative with respect to the second argument — you may call it $\partial_y$ if you want, but there is no $y$ in this formula.
Differentiating this identity with respect to $x$ gives
$$
\partial_1\partial_2g(x,h(x))+h'(x)\partial_2^2g(x,h(x))=0.
$$
Since $\partial_2^2g(x,h(x))\neq0$, you can solve for $h'(x)$.

This can be viewed as a corollary of the implicit function theorem.

Comment: What if $\partial ^2 _y g(x,y) = 0$ at $y=h(x)$?

Comment: @Scott It depends. If it's only zero at one point, that can cause $h$ to be singular unless $\partial_1\partial_2g$ vanishes too. If it's zero throughout but the next derivative never vanishes, you might be able to differentiate one more time and get another equation for $h$. There's no clean answer for what happens when the assumptions are not met, and this is the case also with the implicit function theorem. If you want more details, please ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Very useful, thank you. Is there a way to extend this result to a constrained optimization problem? I.e. when there is a Lagrange multiplier involved. I guess in this case we might have $\partial_2 g(x,h(x))=\lambda(x)$ (where $\lambda$ is a LM) and there isn't much we can do without knowing $\lambda'(x)$.

Comment: @user_lambda Something similar should be possible, but I haven't thought it through. Please ask a separate question about it. I'll take a look, but someone else might well beat me to answering it.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Sounds good. Here is the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753495/derivative-of-argmin-in-a-constraint-problem