# How to minimize non-linear function subject to non-linear constraint involving argmin?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

I have an optimization problem of the form

$$
\min_u f(u)\\
\text{subject to }  \tilde{y} = \mathop{\text{argmin}}_y g(u,y),
$$
where $\tilde{y}$ is provided as a constant.

What are the best algorithms to solve this kind of non-linear optimization?

I found this [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261172/interchange-derivative-and-argmin) above differentiating through $\mathop{\text{argmin}}$, but I'm having trouble putting this into a sequential quadratic programming solver, sensitivity analysis, or something like that.

I'm happy to take first (and second) derivatives of $f$ and $g$ with respect to their arguments, but $f$ and $g$ are not necessarily convex.

Comment: x is a constant.

Comment: In the language of the link you posted, you could understand my constraint as subject to "y solves min_y g(u,y)" and "y - x = 0". The "upper level" objective doesn't depend on y, but y and u are tied together through the "lower level" optimization.

Comment: are you unfamiliar with argmin ? It is similar to min but outputs the value of the argument rather than the objective.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_min

Comment: If $\tilde{y}$ does not depend on $u$, you just have to constrain your optimization on $g(u, \tilde{y})=k$ with $k=\min_u g(u, \tilde{y})$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The lower argmin is over y, how can I swap this with min over u?

Comment: By definition you already know which value of $y$ minimizes $g$, so you need to choose the right value for $u$ to obtain that minimum. Note that this is consequence of the independence of $\tilde{y}$ over $u$.